# SQL remove rows with the same data (not duplicate)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here are the results (don't have 10 reputation points). I would like to eliminate the "duplication" that is indicated by the "***". I'm not sure how to go about this.

```
Client Name----Medication 1------Medication 2
John             Adderall XR       Concerta
John             Adderall XR       Intuniv ER
John             Adderall XR       Risperdal   *** 
John             Adderall XR       Prazosin
John             Risperdal         Concerta
John             Risperdal         Intuniv ER
John             Risperdal         Adderall XR ***
John             Risperdal         Prazosin
```

And here is my query

```
create table #temp5 (medCode int, medText varchar(500), clientid int)

insert into #temp5 (medCode, medText, clientid)
select distinct  
    ClientMedications.MedicationNameId,
    dbo.GetMedicationName(ClientMedications.MedicationNameId),
    Clients.ClientId
from 
    ClientMedications
    join Clients on ClientMedications.ClientId = Clients.ClientId



select distinct
    c.LastName + ' ,' + c.FirstName as [Client Name],
    dbo.GetMedicationName(cm.MedicationNameId) as [Medication 1],
    t1.medText as [Medication 2],
    cmi.InteractionLevel, 
    cmi.ClientMedicationId2
from 
    Clients as c
    join ClientMedications as cm on c.ClientId = cm.ClientId
    join ClientMedicationInteractions as cmi 
        on cm.ClientMedicationId = cmi.ClientMedicationId1
    join #temp5 as t1 on t1.clientId = c.ClientId
where 
    t1.medText != dbo.GetMedicationName(cm.MedicationNameId)
```

Comment: Why do you have two medications in two separate tables in the first place?

Comment: And if so, why do you still have multiple rows for the same client then?

Comment: I hope your tables aren't very large. You have nonSARGable predicates in your where clause and scalar functions. Those are both very bad from a performance perspective.

Comment: You should also check your user defined function usage. GetMedicationName looks like something that fetches names from the table and will perform horribly bad versus just joining the correct table to the sql.

Comment: @SeanLange I am not worried about performance in this case, but say I was, how should I go about correcting this issue of nonSARGable predicates?

Comment: Performance should always be something you consider. It is the second most important piece of writing t-sql and only comes after getting the data correct. I don't know how to steer you in the right path on this one. The not equals predicate will cause a scan no matter what. Even worse is the scalar function on the other side. What that means is it will execute your scalar function for every single row in cm, then it will scan every single row in t1. It would not likely be a somewhat of an effort to fix this because it would take a serious amount of rework.

Answer (score 0):

Create an alpha sorted list of the meds for each line and then dedupe the sorted list.

```
WITH medicationsWithAlphaList
AS
(
     SELECT
        clientname,
        medication1,
        medication2,
        CASE 
            WHEN medication1<medication2
                THEN medication1 +', ' + medication2
            ELSE 
                medication2 + ', ' + medication1 
        END AS medsAlphaList
    FROM
        clientmedications;
)
SELECT
    clientname,
    medication1,
    medication2
FROM
    medicationsWithAlphaList
WHERE
    medsAlphaList IN
        (
        SELECT
            medsAlphaList
        FROM
            medicationsWithAlphaList
        GROUP BY
            medsAlphaList
        HAVING
            COUNT(*)=1
        );
```

Comment: The problem is that the ClientMedications table does not contain a so called medication 1 and medication 2. I created that idea for the sake of interactions between two medications. A row in that table consists of the client and the medication, with multiple rows if the client is on more than one medication.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove the second duplicate row (or the first) then you don't really need the order of the medications. In that case you can put the results from the query in another temporary table say `#temp6` and use `case` to order the two columns like in this example:

```
SELECT distinct
    Name, CASE WHEN med1 > med2 
            THEN med1 + ', ' + med2 
            ELSE med2 + ', ' + med1 
          END as meds
FROM
    (SELECT 'John' as Name, 'Amerral' as med1, 'Metteral' as med2
    UNION
    SELECT 'John', 'Metteral', 'Amerral') medss
```